# Array of Images

Tags: layout, blackberry, user-interface, java-me

I'm working on a blackberry project and for that I need to create grid layout. I'm working on "Blackberry java sdk".

I'm using this code

```
 public class GridScreen extends UiApplication {
// main method
public static void main(String[] args) {

GridScreen theApp = new GridScreen();
UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new GFMScreen());
theApp.enterEventDispatcher();

}

}

// VFM
class GFMScreen extends MainScreen {

public GFMScreen() {

// this doesnt do anything for VCENTER!!
//super(Field.USE_ALL_HEIGHT);

// create a grid field manager, with 2 cols and 0 style param for super class
// style of Manager.FIELD_VCENTER | Field.USE_ALL_HEIGHT doesnt do a thing!
int columns = 2;
final GridFieldManager gfm = new GridFieldManager(columns, 0);

// add some items to the screen
 int size = 6;
 BitmapField[] fRay = new BitmapField[size];
 for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  // create an bitmap field that's centered H + V (inside grid space)
  fRay[i] = new BitmapField(loadBitmap("images/" + (i + 1) + ".png"),
                          Field.FIELD_HCENTER | Field.FIELD_VCENTER | Field.FOCUSABLE);
   gfm.add(fRay[i]);
  }

  // set padding on top/bottom
 {
   // add gfm to screen - this does not center the gfm on the screen... is top aligned        no matter what!
   add(gfm);

     int gfmHeight = 48 * (size / columns);
  int borderHeight = (Display.getHeight() - gfmHeight) / 2;
   gfm.setBorder(BorderFactory.createSimpleBorder(
     new XYEdges(borderHeight, 0, borderHeight, 0),
     Border.STYLE_TRANSPARENT));

   System.out.println("border=" + borderHeight);
   System.out.println("display=" + Display.getHeight());
   System.out.println("gfm=" + gfmHeight);

  }

}

 /** @param res eg "images/icon.png" */
 public static Bitmap loadBitmap(String res) {
  EncodedImage img = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource(res);
  return img.getBitmap();
 }

}// end class
```

What is wrong in this code?
Is there any best approch to create grid layout in BlackBerry.
In above code error is "Display.getHeight() is not define".

Comment: when posting `code` on SO use the code blocks.its alright, We all did mistakes first time(actually all- jonSkeet).

Comment: can you post all the relevant code? I assume that statement is in a loop. Also, what error you getting with above statement? and if not error what unexpected output?

Comment: @MukulGoel- I've posted the all relevent code..

Comment: you have to show us how your `loadBitmap()` method works, or we can't help you much.  also, tell us **what** is going wrong with the code above?  is it throwing an exception?   please be specific.  also, remember to accept and/or upvote answers that help you (accept by checking the "V" icon next to the best answer).  thanks.

Comment: @Nate-actually I'm trying to implement a grid layout for BlackBerry in java and for that i was trying in different ways but i'm unable to implement.Can you please tell me what should I do?

Comment: once again, **you have to show us how your loadBitmap() method works** (the code).  and, telling us *"this is also not working"* is not helpful.  **what** is not working?

Comment: sorry i'm updating all code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this code helps:

```
Bitmap[] images = new Bitmap[6];
for ((int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
   string filename = "images/" + String.valueOf(i + 1) + ".png"; 
   images[i] = Bitmap.getBitmapResource(filename);  
   }               
}
```

Comment: @MeNoMore- I'm not interested to store all the images which is present in the Imagefolder. I want to create an array of few selected images which is present in the imagefolder. any help??

Comment: This is for BlackBerry Java, not desktop Java.  The classes (and paths) your code uses do not exist on BlackBerry.

Comment: what is the criteria to decide which images are to be added to the array?

Comment: @GauravSakhardande- nothing.I want to add the images as per my wish.

Comment: @MeNoMore -this error is generating please look "The method createImage(String) is undefined for the type Image".

Comment: createImage(String): http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/3.7api/javax/microedition/lcdui/Image.html#createImage(java.lang.String)

Comment: @MeNoMore-dude can you tell me How can we get the images from an array of images.